# Wrap substring in double quotes if it's not in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

The below @font-face CSS directive does not work in IE 11 unless the font-family is wrapped in double quotes manually which is what I want to automate using regex. I've come close so far but struggling to detect if the matched string has quotes or not.

```
'@font-face {font-style: normal;font-family: f11;font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal; }'.replace(/font-family\:(.*?)\;/, "font-family: \"$1\";");
```

If you run following string in console, you'll see,

```
@font-face {font-style: normal;font-family: " f11";font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal; }
```

Two things I want to do:

1. Remove space from the matched string, currently it's `<SPACE>f11`.
2. Check for quotes in the match.

Comment: @Biffen: Thanks for the quick reply. Check the updates above.

Comment: `replace(/font-family:\s*([^"]+?);/, "font-family: \"$1\";")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replace(/font-family:\s*([^"]+?);/, "font-family: \"$1\";")
```

Solves both #1 and #2.

```
'@font-face {font-style: normal;font-family: f11;font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal; }'.replace(/font-family:\s*([^"]+?);/, "font-family: \"$1\";");
```

↓

```
@font-face {font-style: normal;font-family: "f11";font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal; }
```

And if already quoted:

```
'@font-face {font-style: normal;font-family: "f11";font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal; }'.replace(/font-family:\s*([^"]+?);/, "font-family: \"$1\";");
```

↓

```
@font-face {font-style: normal;font-family: "f11";font-variant: normal;font-weight: normal; }
```